# Model Binding with Forms: IEnumerable<ModelName> vs. IEnumerable<Object>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to learn to program with Asp.Net MVC and am struggling to understand this. Can someone please explain the following:

If I use the following ViewModel, Controller, and View, the ModelState.IsValid in the POST method evaluates to **true**, and I am able to work with the data from the form.

#### ViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; } 

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public int UsersCompany { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public IEnumerable<object> Companies { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<object> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

```
// GET: /Users/Create
public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
{
    RegisterViewModel registerViewModel = new RegisterViewModel();

    //Get the list of Roles
    var allRoles = await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();

    registerViewModel.Roles = allRoles.ToList();
      ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
            .FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

    var company = await db.CompanyModels.FindAsync(user.CompanyModelId);

    var companyAcct = await db.CompanyAccountModels.FindAsync(company.CompanyAccountModelId);

    var companies = db.CompanyModels
            .Where(c => c.CompanyAccountModelId == companyAcct.Id);

    registerViewModel.UsersCompany = user.CompanyModelId;
    registerViewModel.Companies = companies;

    return View(registerViewModel);
}
```

#### View Snippet

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Companies, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Companies, new SelectList(Model.Companies, "Id", "CompanyName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Companies, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

But if I use a type of MyModel in the ViewModel IEnumerable, as shown below, the following error occurs when ModelState is checked in the POST method:

Message "The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'xyz.Models.CompanyModel' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."    string

I am reading this error in the values field in the live variable data you can see when in debugger mode with breakpoints.

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    //snipped

    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public IEnumerable<CompanyModel> Companies { get; set; }

    //snipped
}
```

So the main question is just around why this happens, and a related question is should I be doing anything differently here. Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Please also feel free to comment on any bad practices or boneheaded things I'm doing within this code.

Comment: Are you trying to select a company to be assigned to the user in a dropdownlist? (you cannot bind a `<select>` element to a collection - you need to bind to `int UsersCompany` and then you need a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property for the list of companies to be displayed in the dropdownlist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument in the `Html.DropDownListFor` method is the value which will be filled by the selected item in the dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    c => c.Companies, // the selected item in the collection (this is the problem line)
    new SelectList(Model.Companies, "Id", "CompanyName"), // the collection
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The line from the code above is trying to bind the selected value from the dropdown (the `Id` property of the selected `CompanyModel`) to the entire collection of `CompanyModel`s.

The reason that `IEnumerable<object>` works is because MVC is able to bind the selected value and turn it into a `IEnumerable<object>` with only one item in it  (which is some company `Id` as a string). MVC can figure out how to bind `"2"` to an `IEnumerable<object>`, but not an `IEnumerable<CompanyModel>`.

What you'll want to do instead is to create a property for the selected value. Here's an example:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public IEnumerable<CompanyModel> Companies { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? SelectedCompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.SelectedCompanyId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.SelectedCompanyId, new SelectList(Model.Companies, "Id", "CompanyName"), new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedCompanyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand. There's still something going on that's keeping what I'm trying to do from working, but I don't understand my new issue enough to ask a good follow up question.

Comment: I've found that if I start writing a question which thoroughly explains my issue, I often end up finding the answer myself before I have to hit the "Post" button. Might be worth giving it a try. =)

Comment: Figured it out. I had forgot to change the `[Bind(Include = "xyz")]` statement on the POST method after I made the updates. Works perfectly now!